# How to detect aging signs with ARkit / AR foundation?

Tags: unity, augmented-reality

How Do I approach the matter of detecting skin color, wrinkles, age estimation using ARkit / AR foundation in unity ?
I haven't found any tutorials online that can help on this.

Comment: It sounds like the part of this project you're having trouble with is not the game mechanics, which we can help you with here, but with the computer vision component. Most games ever made don't do skin colour detection or age estimation, so it's not a topic you'll find most game developers are experts in. Instead, you may want to consult [this Q&A on which StackExchange site to go to for computer vision questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2794/67684). Once you understand the libraries/algorithms to use, we can help you with the game-side integration part.

Answer (score 1):

## You don't, and can't.

Although ARKit/ARFoundation has face detection algorithms employed, it is only used for detecting landmarks and converting that into virtual space coordinates, of which you can scale/whatever your objects around.

ARKit/ARFoundation is a high-level API used for generating points; landmarks to map the virtual world space onto the real world.

You'll need to employ your own algorithm onto the image in order to do this.